# No chef commands work after amazon ec2 instance restart

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I restarted the amazon ec2 instance and now none of the my knife commands work.

Please help me experts. Thanks

Comment: Did you setup Chef via a User Data setup script? User Data only runs on first boot, so you'd need to configure it to start as a service for future restarts.

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me to. Worked after chef restart. But restart all service list.

Check all service list with below command.

sudo chef-server-ctl service-list

chef-server-ctl restart SERVICE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing ChefDK and using Bash as your shell, run this:

```
echo 'eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```